# How much power do quantum computers use based on the number of qubits being allocated?

Tags: experimental-realization

How much power do quantum computers use based on the number of qubits being allocated? If it's not based on qubits, What determines how much power quantum computers use?

Note: A [similar question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/1499/5889) was asked about 1 year ago, and therefore relatively outdated.

Comment: I don't think much changed since the other question was asked.. it's still highly dependent on the architecture